# Why do our service fabric actor reminders stop working?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful, service-fabric-actor

We use service fabric actor reminders to perform a de-queue mechanism.  The reminders fire every 5 seconds unless the actor is busy de-queuing lots of messages otherwise it will fire when the thread finishes working.  We have 30 actors running on this pattern simultaneously.  The actors state is set to "Persisted".  As I understand it the reminders should be persisted and should live across service moves, fail over, deactivation etc.

The problem we are facing is that when there are errors elsewhere in the system, timeouts for example, then these actor reminders stop.  We have a tenanted system and gradually the reminders stop for every customer as once they stop for one customer queues start to build up and this causes more errors and more actors reminders to stop working.

What would cause reminders to stop working like this?

Comment: How many partitions did you assign to the actorservice?

Comment: Each actor service has 2 partitions

Comment: Did you check performance counters to see if high load on memory / cpu / disk is causing resource starvation?